# unable to change mouse acceleration profile with Logitec G402

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, kde, mouse

im using **Kubuntu 20.10** with no tweaks.

mouse acceleration profile on system settings doesnt do anything. also mouse speed setting is weird. i set my mouse speed on windows as 720dpi and it is too fast on kde with level 2 speed, but level 1 is too slow. speed adjusting slider has too big range.
i can tell changing mouse acceleration profile settings does somthing since mouse speed adjusting slider's range changes when i change profile.

i tried x11-related commands.

`xinput set-prop <device> "libinput Accel Speed"`

this changed speed but nothing else. and it is kinda broken like system settings.

`xinput set-prop <device> "Coordinate Transformation Matrix"`

only changes speed.

`xinput set-prop <device> "libinput Accel Profile Enabled"`

does nothing.

`xset m <acceleration> <threshold>`

does nothing.

i was on dirty system which is upgraded from customized **kubuntu 18.04** to 20.04 so i tried with official **kubuntu 20.04** live image but faced same issue.
i have clean-installed **kubuntu 20.10** but it didnt solved problem.

====UPDATE-Dec-10====

i checked some distributions:

- Ubuntu 20.10
- Lubuntu 20.10
- Fedora (latest network install)

all of these are affected. im suspecting it is driver issue.
i tried to test on Debian but i couldnt due to missing display driver.
i thought further testing on other distribution is no longer needed since Fedora, away from widespread Debian-based systems, is affected.
or this is just my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that on the code side, in the Linux world "acceleration" is what everyone else would call "sensitivity". Getting actual mouse acceleration with libinput apparently requires defining [custom acceleration profiles](https://www.mankier.com/4/libinput#Custom_Acceleration_Profile) because its "adaptive" profile does hardly anything. So this is quite the hassle.

I would suggest switching the mouse driver to [evdev](https://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/PointerAcceleration/) which comes with multiple useful acceleration profiles (suggestion: go with their recommendation of "polynomial" (2))

```
Section "InputClass"
     Identifier "Logitech Gaming Mouse G400"
     MatchIsPointer "yes"
     Driver "evdev"

     Option "AccelerationProfile" "2"
     Option "VelocityScale" "3"
     Option "ConstantDeceleration" "10"
     Option "AdaptiveDeceleration" "1"
EndSection
```

You can set the properties via cli using `xinput`. [xinput](https://www.mankier.com/1/xinput) uses the `device property`, also given in the [documentation](https://www.mankier.com/4/libinput#Custom_Acceleration_Profile)

*edit:* it bugged me so much that I dove into libinput acceleration profiles and wrote a user friendly [GUI program](https://codeberg.org/br4nnigan/libinput_pointer_acceleration_configurator) to customize it. It's much more flexible than using udev.